# Very non-random factor of Math.random when filling an array with random numbers

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, random

If an array is filled like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rand.length; i++) {
    rand[i] = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000) + 1;
}
```

and then sorted using Arrays.sort or any sorting algorithm for that matter, if one does

```
int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < rand.length;i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            sum += rand[i] + rand[rand.length - 1 -i];
        }
        else
            sum -= rand[i] + rand[rand.length - 1 - i];
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println(sum);
```

then the sum will always be zero. This has shown to be true for the hundred or so times I have tested it. Try any range, any array length.

I can't imagine that the psuedo-randomness would really be that flawed. What's going on here?

Comment: "any array length"... Are you sure? Try int[] rand = new int[1001]; See the great explanation from @duskwuff

Comment: Random ra=new Random(); rand[i]= ra.nextInt(3300000); also return the same result.

Comment: I completely forgot that it iterates to the top of the array and not halfway through... This makes sense now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't matter what numbers your random number generator comes up with. So long as your array has an even length, the sum that you calculate using that function will always be zero.

Let's prove this mathematically. Let's say we have an array of four elements: `[A, B, C, D]`. (The values don't matter, and I'll prove it.)

For each time around the loop:

- `i = 0`: `sum += A + D`. Sum is now `A + D`.
- `i = 1`: `sum -= B + C`. Sum is now `(A + D) - (B + C)`.
- `i = 2`: `sum += C + B`. Sum is now `(A + D) - (B + C) + (C + B)`
- `i = 3`: `sum -= D + A`. Sum is now `(A + D) - (B + C) + (C + B) - (D + A)`.

If we expand this, we get `A + D - B - C + C + B - D - A`. Everything cancels out; the result is zero. Always.

The same principle applies to any even-length array. Each number ends up getting added twice and subtracted twice, so it all cancels out.

Comment: Right - like I said, so long as the array has an even length.

Answer (score 4):

If the length is even, you add all the numbers once and subtract all of them once – of course, the result is 0.

Example with `length==6`:

```
/*i==0*/  sum += rand[0] + rand[5];
/*i==1*/  sum -= rand[1] + rand[4];
/*i==2*/  sum += rand[2] + rand[3];
/*i==3*/  sum -= rand[3] + rand[2];
/*i==4*/  sum += rand[4] + rand[1];
/*i==5*/  sum -= rand[5] + rand[0];
```

Did you try any uneven lengths?